# Problems assigning values to a Dataframe cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am working combining different pandas Dataframes and sorting the index of the final dataframe I found something that does not make any sense to me. It gives no error but no assignation really happens. I give a simplified example below

Case 1:

```
import pandas as pd


ind_1 = ['a','a','b','c','c']
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=ind_1,columns=['col1','col2'])

df_1.col1.loc['a'].iloc[0] = 1
df_1.col1.loc['b'] = 2
df_1.col1.loc['c'].iloc[0] = 3

print('Original df_1')
print(df_1)

# Original df_1
#   col1 col2
# a    1  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
# b    2  NaN
# c    3  NaN
# c  NaN  NaN
```

You can see that this assignation works fine. But let's create the dataframe from the index sorted differently.

```
ind_1_sorted = sorted(ind_1,reverse=True)
df_1_sorted = pd.DataFrame(index=ind_1_sorted,columns=['col1','col2'])

df_1_sorted.col1.loc['a'].iloc[0] = 1
df_1_sorted.col1.loc['b'] = 2
df_1_sorted.col1.loc['c'].iloc[0] = 3

print('Sorted df_1')
print(df_1_sorted)

# Sorted df_1
#  col1 col2
# c  NaN  NaN
# c  NaN  NaN
# b    2  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
```

You can see now that the assignation only works for the non-repeated index. I thought that the problem had to be related with the sorting but let's see next case.

Case 2:

```
ind_2 = ['c','c','b','a','a']
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(index=ind_2,columns=['col1','col2'])

df_2.col1.loc['a'].iloc[0] = 1
df_2.col1.loc['b'] = 2
df_2.col1.loc['c'].iloc[0] = 3

print('Original df_2')
print(df_2)

# Original df_2
#  col1 col2
# c  NaN  NaN
# c  NaN  NaN
# b    2  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
```

Now, we get no assignation without implementing the sorting. Let's see what happens if I sort the index

```
ind_2_sorted = sorted(ind_2,reverse=False)
df_2_sorted = pd.DataFrame(index=ind_2_sorted,columns=['col1','col2'])

df_2_sorted.col1.loc['a'].iloc[0] = 1
df_2_sorted.col1.loc['b'] = 2
df_2_sorted.col1.loc['c'].iloc[0] = 3

print('Sorted df_2')
print(df_2_sorted)

# Sorted df_2
#   col1 col2
# a    1  NaN
# a  NaN  NaN
# b    2  NaN
# c    3  NaN
# c  NaN  NaN
```

And now, the assignation works after the sorting!! The only difference I see is that the assignation works when the index is sorted in a "standard way" (alphabetically in this case). Has this any sense?

In case the solution is using first a index sorted alphabetically and then sort it in the order I want, how could I do this sorting using repeated indexes as in these examples?

Thanks!

Comment: I think, this is related to the chained assignment problematics, and you simply do not get the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Check the [pandas-documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). In a nutshell: you should not set elements like you are doing ;)

Comment: I agree with @Quickbeam2k1. Pandas documenation explains that assignment may fail with chained indexing without error or warning. It happens because you may assign value to the copy of original data which is absolutely legal but not what you want (just like mutable vs immutable data types). It's not a bug but Python feature I guess. So be careful with chained indexing in pandas. Also it may be a good habit to always use `.loc/.at` syntax for indexing.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Very precise identification of the issue here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As User Quickbeam2k1 mentioned, the issue is due to chain assignment.

Index Objects have a method called `get_loc` which can be used to convert labels to positions, however its return type is polymorphic & that is why I prefer to not use it.

Using `np.nonzero` & filtering on the dataframe's index & column, we can convert the labels to positional references & modify the dataframe using `iloc` instead of `loc`

i.e. your first code sample can be rewritten as:

```
# original
df_1.col1.loc['a'].iloc[0] = 1
df_1.col1.loc['b'] = 2
df_1.col1.loc['c'].iloc[0] = 3

# works for all indices
col1_mask = df_1.columns == 'col1'
a_mask, = np.nonzero(df_1.index == 'a')
b_mask, = np.nonzero(df_1.index == 'b')
c_mask, = np.nonzero(df_1.index == 'c')
df_1.iloc[a_mask[0], col1_mask] = 1
df_1.iloc[b_mask, col1_mask] = 1
df_1.iloc[c_mask[0], col1_mask] = 3
```

Similarly for the other examples